# Change the size of the partition using parted

Tags: partition, gparted, parted, resize2fs

What am I doing wrong?

I have an image, I added it as a loop device:

```
losetup -P /dev/loop13 ./my_image.img
```

gparted screenshot:
[image: gparted screenshot]

Then I try to change the FS size for the partition first:

```
e2fsck -f /dev/loop13p1
resize2fs /dev/loop13p1 7G
```

It outputs:

```
Resizing the filesystem on /dev/loop13p1 to 1835008 (4k) blocks.
The filesystem on /dev/loop13p1 is now 1835008 (4k) blocks long.
```

Then I shrink the section itself:

```
parted /dev/loop13p1 resizepart 1 7G
```

gparted screenshot:
[image: gparted screenshot]

After which I perform:

```
resize2fs /dev/loop13p1
```

Output

```
Resizing the filesystem on /dev/loop13p1 to 3659264 (4k) blocks.
The filesystem on /dev/loop13p1 is now 3659264 (4k) blocks long.
```

And it rolls back to the original value...

gparted screenshot:
[image: gparted screenshot]

**UPD**

I tried to reduce the partition via sfdisk and I succeeded, but now I don't understand why even more...

```
resize2fs -p /dev/loop13p1 7G
echo '2048,7G' | sfdisk /dev/loop13 -N 1
resize2fs /dev/loop13p1
```

Output:

```
The filesystem is already 1835008 (4k) blocks long.  Nothing to do!
```

gparted screenshot:
[image]

Comment: @Marcus I don't need to do these actions via **Gparted**, I need to via **parted**. The title and tags were initially correct.

Comment: oh, sorry my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use parted correctly, you unfortunately have to do a little math sometimes.

> ```
> parted /dev/loop13p1 resizepart 1 7G
> ```

This command probably does not do what you expect.

`parted` works with block devices that have partition tables on them. So in the case of `/dev/loop13p1` it would be a partition table on a partition. Resizing partition 1 of that would mean you're trying to resize a (fictional) device like `/dev/loop13-p1-p1`.

You probably want to use `/dev/loop13` here.

Then, `resizepart 1 7G` does not resize partition 1 to 7G of size.

The syntax for resizepart is `resizepart NUMBER END`. END, not SIZE.

So it moves the end point of partition 1 to the offset 7G. The size of the partition then depends on the start sector of partition 1. If the partition starts at 1MiB it would be 7G minus 1MiB large. Too small for a filesystem of 7G size.

Furthermore, for parted, G means GB (power of 1000) not GiB (power of 1024). So the unit itself can also be an additional source of confusion. If you resize to G when you meant GiB, the partition will be way too small.

Finally for new partition sizes to take, the kernel has to successfully re-read the partition table. Sometimes this fails if the device is in use etc. so always double check with lsblk, blockdev --getsize64, etc. or via `head /sys/block/loop13/loop13p1/{start,size}` what size the kernel currently believes it to be.

---

> ```
> The filesystem on /dev/loop13p1 is now 1835008 (4k) blocks long.
> ```

`1835008 * 4096 = 7516192768`

So the partition must be 7516192768 bytes or larger.

```
# parted /dev/loop0 unit b print free
Model: Loopback device (loopback)
Disk /dev/loop0: 15032385536B
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags:

Number  Start     End           Size          Type     File system  Flags
        1024B     1048575B      1047552B               Free Space
 1      1048576B  15032385535B  15031336960B  primary  ext2
```

Trying resizepart:

```
# parted /dev/loop0 resizepart 1 7G
Warning: Shrinking a partition can cause data loss, are you sure you want to continue?

Yes/No? Yes

# parted /dev/loop0 unit b print free
Model: Loopback device (loopback)
Disk /dev/loop0: 15032385536B
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags:

Number  Start        End           Size         Type     File system  Flags
        1024B        1048575B      1047552B              Free Space
 1      1048576B     7000000511B   6998951936B  primary  ext2
        7000000512B  15032385535B  8032385024B           Free Space
```

After `resizepart 1 7G` the partition ends at (around) 7GB (7000000511B) which is way smaller than the required 7516192768B.

```
# parted /dev/loop0 resizepart 1 7GiB
Information: You may need to update /etc/fstab.

# parted /dev/loop0 unit b print free
Model: Loopback device (loopback)
Disk /dev/loop0: 15032385536B
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags:

Number  Start        End           Size         Type     File system  Flags
        1024B        1048575B      1047552B              Free Space
 1      1048576B     7516192767B   7515144192B  primary  ext2
        7516192768B  15032385535B  7516192768B           Free Space
```

After `resizepart 1 7GiB`, the partition ends (around) 7GiB (7516192768 Bytes). This is closer but still too small since we have to consider 1 MiB (1048576B) offset.

So there is no easy command to get it right, you just have to do the math yourself.

```
# parted /dev/loop0 resizepart 1 $((1+7*1024))MiB
Information: You may need to update /etc/fstab.

# parted /dev/loop0 unit b print free

Model: Loopback device (loopback)
Disk /dev/loop0: 15032385536B
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags:

Number  Start        End           Size         Type     File system  Flags
        1024B        1048575B      1047552B              Free Space
 1      1048576B     7517241343B   7516192768B  primary  ext2
        7517241344B  15032385535B  7515144192B           Free Space
```

Only then have we reached the desired partition size of 7516192768 Bytes.

Comment: Oh, thanks, i will try and I will write the result later

Comment: @Keonik it's not wrong to use `sfdisk`, if it suits your needs better. It's more script oriented and it uses size, not end, so it does the math for you.